# NSolve stalls when given an equation containing Log

Tags: equation-solving

Why does `NSolve` not work for this type of equation?

```
2.01224 == (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a) Log[
    9 (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a)] + (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a) Log[
    9/4 (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a)]
```

Here is my full script, where I solve got `a`, it just hangs there:

```
NSolve[2.01224 == (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a) Log[
    9 (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a)] + (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a) Log[
    9/4 (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a), ], a]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By restricting the domain to `Reals`, I got an answer quite quickly.

```
NSolve[
  2.01224 == 
    (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a) Log[9 (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a)] + (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a) 
    Log[9/4 (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a)],
  a, Reals]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
>
> ```
> {{a -> -0.000139109}}
> ```

Checking the result

```
(0.954875 - 0.0084496 a) Log[9 (0.954875 - 0.0084496 a)] + 
  (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a) Log[9/4 (0.0113946 - 0.00295146 a)] /. 
  a -> -0.00013910870308745475`
```

> ```
> 2.01224
> ```